# Border RadCheckBox Telerik

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove this black border that appears when clicking on the checkbox
using bootstrap 4.4.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLOs3.png)

Comment: I removed C tag because it doesn't appear to be a C programming related question apparently.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try by set style `style="outline:none !important;  outline-width: 0 !important;  box-shadow: none;  -moz-box-shadow: none;  -webkit-box-shadow: none;}`